# Paypal express checkout error when selling digital goods

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I'm trying to add PayPal express checkout to my site to sell digital goods, but i get error "You are not signed up to accept payment for digitally delivered goods" when i use SetExpressCheckout from SDK. How can i enable this feature in my sandbox account?

It looks like a know issue for PayPal sandbox account, but i couldn't find working solution.

EDIT 1:

I found something in sandbox site: My business setup -> View all products ->PayPal for Digital Goods (Express Checkout)-> Apply now. And now my payment solution is "PayPal Digital Goods (Express Checkout)" instead of "Payments Pro", but i still get the same error.

EDIT 2: I removed

```
itemDetails.ItemCategory = ItemCategoryType.DIGITAL;
```

and now Express Checkout seems to work fine. But now another question: do i need to define this property to use Express Checkout in production?

Comment: Can you provide the email address for your test sandbox seller account and I will take a look how the account is configured on my end and make sure that it is set up correctly.

Comment: Yes, sure. My sandbox account email is cafetestmerchant@gmail.com

Comment: I could not find an account with this email address.  Please make sure this is the email address of your actual test sandbox seller account and not the email address that you log into developer.paypal.com with.

Comment: Maybe this one "cafetestmerchant-2@gmail.com"?

Answer (score 0):

Digital Goods was not enabled on this account.  I have enabled it, can you try testing with this now and see if it works.

Comment: so what solution do i have to use to sell digital files from my site, receive payments directly on my site with credit card and send money from my site? can it be done with Paypal for Digital goods? i don't know what solution to choose, almost every day i find something new. Great thanks to terrible documentation and tons of outdated information. can you explain me the structure of paypal plans? On top we have Paypal standart, paypal advanced and pro? and i can add to them some options such as digital goods and other?